# In review queue, refreshing an edited question drops comment-in-progress and disables "add comment" link

Tags: bug, comments, review

I was [reviewing a post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/16566#58937) and had typed half a comment. The grey bar with "*this post was edited -- click here to reload*" or similar popped up. I clicked it. The changes loaded fine, but my half-written comment disappeared and the *add comment* link now does nothing when clicked. (Not disabled; simply had no effect.)

Refreshing the page restored the link's functionality, but I still lost my comment text. :<

Low priority, I know; just putting this out there.

Comment: Yeah, I wish comments got saved - I've lost a few that way.  I suppose comments are the black sheep of Stack Overflow, but still.